# I am trying to append every tr to a div but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, clone

I want to append every `tr` to a `div`, but it doesnt seem to work.
if I go with `$(someTableRow).clone().appendTo(theDiv)` it doesnt do nothing when I click the button.
if I go with `$(theDiv).append(someTableRow)` it appends but it goes, 3 table rows instead to the div, then one, and one, since it has only 5, why does this happen?

```
@model IEnumerable<webAplikacijaScafolding.Models.Album>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ArtistId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AlbumArtUrl)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="tRows">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtistId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>



                <img width="200" height="100" src="@Url.Content(item.AlbumArtUrl)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.AlbumId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AlbumId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.AlbumId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<button id="button">Click for Day offer</button>

<div id="discount">




</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#button ").click(function () {
                var b = document.getElementsByClassName('tRows');

                /*  $(b[2]).clone().appendTo("#discount");*/


                for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    $(b[i]).clone().appendTo("#discount");

                }

            })

        })

    </script>

}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to mean when a `<tr>` is stuck into a `<div>`?

Comment: The HTML structure `<div><tr></tr></div>` is not valid HTML and the browser will "fix" it by adding the missing `<table>` and `<tbody>` (or by removing the `<tr>`, couldn't guess which as I've never attempted such folly)

Comment: What are your actually trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Fixed it, the problem was that the <tr> i added had class "tRows" so, when adding them to the div, i added them with that class so my loop was getting endless.